# An affine morphism of schemes over $k$ is closed iff the pullback over Spec $\bar k \to$ Spec $k$ is

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

On page 250, Vakil states that an affine morphism of schemes $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$ is a closed embedding iff so is $\pi\times \bar k:X\times_k\bar k\rightarrow Y\times_k\bar k$.

The only if direction is easy. $\pi^\#: A \rightarrow B$ is surjective $\Rightarrow A \otimes_k \bar k\rightarrow B \otimes_k \bar k$ is surjective.

But how do I prove the other direction? What are examples of when it fails if we replace $\bar k$ by $l$, a non-algebraically closed extension, or by $\bar k(t)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with it being $\overline{k}$. This just follows from the fact that $k\to\overline{k}$ is faithfully flat. This is clear since it's flat (everything is flat over $k$) and the induced map $\text{spec}(\overline{k})\to \text{spec}(k)$ is surjective.

Perhaps easier, merely note that $(B\otimes_k \overline{k})/(A\otimes_k \overline{k})=(B/A)\otimes_k\overline{k}$, and note that $\dim_k B/A=\dim_{\overline{k}}(B/A)\otimes_k\overline{k}$.